# ADD CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS (Oracle 11g, Postgres 8)

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, constraints, exists

I'm having difficult to make one script to delete the old constraints from some databases and after, create new ones with new references.

The problem is that the databases are not equal.

eg.: the `swpmnh` database has the `fk_cmp_solicitaca_rh_contrat` constraint but the `swpmcs` database has not. So if I execute the script I would have an error and it won't commit.

I know that Postgres 9.x has the possibility to do `DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS`, but neither Postgres 8.x nor Oracle 11g have this function.

I'm working and studying `SQL` about only 3 months, I know that this is a simple thing, but it's being a problem for me.

Comment: The databases have differences, no way around it. One thing I noticed is both of them keep going after errors, so just put the 'same' code twice, one for each ;)

Comment: The databases still have differences, the idea is let them equal, with time. I didn't understand your point man, sorry. At top of the script I've put  the ´BEGIN´ and at end I've put the 'COMMIT'. So, if I have any error, it won't execute nothing

Comment: All Postgres 8.x versions are end-of-life (8.4 will only be supported for 2 more months from now on). So there is absolutely no reason to use Postgres 8.x for anything new

Comment: I normally did scripts for creating the db structure, so there's no need for committing, and this allowed me to cheat; I didn't have any commits at all.

Comment: You *could* use a macro processor and generate 2 different scripts, one for postgresql and one for oracle from the same source ... every C compiler comes with one, or you could use something like m4 ... not sure I'd recommend it; hopefully somebody has a better idea

Comment: I'm doing one script for postgres and another for oracle. The problem is practically solved. Really thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the error you will be getting:

```
SQL> alter table my_tab drop constraint my_cons;
alter table my_tab drop constraint my_cons
                                   *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02443: Cannot drop constraint  - nonexistent constraint
```

You can trap the ORA-02443 error in PL/SQL and ignore it (using dynamic SQL):

```
  1  declare
  2     e exception;
  3     pragma exception_init (e, -2443);
  4  begin
  5     execute immediate 'alter table my_tab drop constraint my_cons';
  6  exception
  7     when e then null;
  8* end;
SQL> /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

That is a bit verbose, so you could create a handy procedure:

```
create or replace procedure drop_constraint (p_table varchar2, p_constraint varchar2) is
   e exception;
   pragma exception_init (e, -2443);
begin
   execute immediate 'alter table ' || p_table || ' drop constraint '||p_constraint;
exception
   when e then null;
end;
```

Then use it whenever you need it:

```
execute drop_constraint ('my_tab', 'my_cons1');
execute drop_constraint ('my_tab', 'my_cons2');
execute drop_constraint ('another_tab', 'another_cons');
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer man.
Let me check if I got it:

I have a lot of constraints on my script, so I have to declare the exception whenever I drop one constraint?
Another doubt, can I do this on postgres?

Thank you!

Comment: If you create the procedure then you can call it many times over without declaring the exception.  This is for Oracle, I don't know Postgres at all.